# Powershell : passing parameters to a function

Tags: powershell, function, types, parameters

I'm trying to create a function which takes two parameters and do some repetitive tasks, but the execution fails :
Here is the function :

```
Function RenameFolderFiles{
    param(
        [String[]]$FldPath, [String]$TypeFld
    )
    
    Write-Host $TypeFld " : " $FldPath.Length
    Write-Host $FldPath
    for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $FldPath.Length; $i++ ) {
        write-host $i " : " $FldPath.FullName[$i]
        $NewFld = ([string]$FldPath.FullName[$i]).Replace(" _ tt","");
    }
}
```

I call the function like this :

```
$Fld = Get-ChildItem -Path "$varCheminRepertoireScript" -Recurse -Directory | Where-Object {$_.FullName -like "* _ tt*"}

RenameFolderFiles -FldPath $Fld -TypeFld "Nb of Folders & Sub-Folders"
```

But the result is :

```
.
.
.
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Test.ps1:10 char:9
+         write-host $i " : " $FldPath.FullName[$i]
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

What is wrong with the parameters / types passed ?
Thanks for your clarifications !!
BR

Comment: What's the last output written to the screen immediately _before_ the error is thrown? Does it happen on the first iteration, or later?

Comment: Thanks Mathias, It happens on the first iteration.
Here is the result
```
Nb of Folders & Sub-Folders  :  24

Conve...      #here is the printout of $FldPath which is too long for this response

Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Files_2022\Privé\PowerShell\Rename_s-lib.org_files_S_220930.ps1:67 char:9
+         write-host $i " : " $FldPath.FullName[$i]
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

And the rest of the output is similar for all 24 values

Comment: Are you by any chance using PowerShell 2.0 or 3.0? You can check the version by inspecting `$PSVersionTable`

Answer (score 1):

There is No property like FullName on string[] $FldPath or on  $FldPath[0] index Item
$FldPath.FullName

set [object[]]$FldPath instead of [String[]]$FldPath in param of Function

Comment: I think you're right, but your answer is poor with a statement as "Check your code again" (it is more like a comment). Please add some explanation and background to it.

Comment: Thanks ABC DEF for the answer.
But when I check the $FldPath.Length, it reports 24 (in my test). How can I address these 24 different values in $FldPath ?

Comment: @StartingPS `$FldPath[$i].FullName`

Comment: set  [object[]]$FldPath instead of [String[]]$FldPath in param of Function